# match() against() doesn't work all the time

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

so I was trying this simple query : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3c5e/2

full text search does work with some words but doesn't with others .

 words that work : `eeeee` `Godgo`

 words that doesn't work : `Said` `saw`

 can someone tell me the reason for this different behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the minimum and maximum word length full-text parameters apply:
>   innodb_ft_min_token_size and innodb_ft_max_token_size for InnoDB
>   search indexes, and ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len for MyISAM
>   ones.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

The minimum default length is 4 i think

Comment: yup seems that's the reason .Thanks !Do you know by any chance way to override this limit ?

Comment: I wont lie,I have no clue,there might be some solutions in the comment section of that link.

Comment: Ofcourse you can change the values in those parameters but without that i dont know.

Comment: I read that you need to contact the admin of your server administrator to change the MySQL configuration file which is practically impossible cause it will demand him to change every single FULLTEXT index around .

Comment: yeah seems I will work around this issue using this. Thanks mate