# MySQL fulltext index search not returned expected results

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I got a mysql `products` table which is has below fields:

```
  id  |     name     |  manufacturer
_____________________________________
  1   | MacBook Air  |  Apple
_____________________________________
  2   | MacBook Pro  |  Apple
_____________________________________
  3   | Galaxy S3    |  Samsung
```

When I perform a fulltext search by below query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (name, manufacturer) AGAINST ('air pro galaxy')
```

it is only returned result for `row 3` instead of `row 1, 2 and 3`.

I guess fulltext search doesn't look for the second text to perform a search?

Another question regarding to fulltext index search, When I tried to add a new field let's say `price`, with `int` data type, in phpmyadmin, I cannot index `int` as fulltext, does it means fulltext index is not allow for numeric or integer type?

Please advise me, thanks!

Comment: I think that fulltext searches ignore "short" words (less than 3 or 4 characters), so that'd possibly be why the `air` and `pro` parts aren't found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162158/match-against-doesnt-work-all-the-time/19162700#19162700

Comment: You probably need to tweak a few server variables and restart/re-index
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length